# Update parent array data from child component using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react.

I have array of records, and want to set one of the records data using handleChange

Below is parent component

```
const RecordPreview = ({ matchRecords, homeTeamId, awayTeamId, isAdmin, isRecordAdmin }) => {

  const [records, setRecords] = useState(matchRecords);
  const teams = useSelector(selectTeams, shallowEqual)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const selectedId = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    setRecords(matchRecords)
  }, [matchRecords]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRecords(records)
  }, [records]);


  const handleChange = records.First.Id(??) = event => {
    //setRecords({ ...records.find(record => record.id === event.value), scoreMemberId: event.value })

    // const { name, value } = event.target;

    // setMembers({ ...members, [name]: value });
    // member => setRecords({ ...records, scoreMemberId: member.value })
  }
```

From child, I have one of record data and trying to pass record.id to parent and set matched recordId with selected value.

```
      <CustomDropdown
            name='member'
            value={assistMemberId}
            handleChange={handleChange(record.id)}
            options={memberOptions.filter(member => member.teamId === teamId)}
            required
        /> :
```

My question is whether there is a way to update selectedDropdownValue from child component to update parent array.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: If there is a better way to pass update one of records from parent array, please let me know.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to add some value which you get from a form in the child component to an array(state) in the parent component?